# Sliding mode stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Given the scalar system

$$
\dot{x} = -\text{sgn}(x) \tag{1}
$$

with

$$
\text{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & x < 0 \\
0 & x = 0 \\
1 & x > 0 \,.
\end{cases}
$$

What is an easy method to check for stability? And: Say I use quasi sliding mode with

$$
\dot{x} = -\tanh(a x) \,. \tag{2}
$$

If it is shown that $(2)$ is stable for all $a > 0$, does that also show stability of $(1)$ because

$$
\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \tanh(a x) = \text{sgn}(x) \,?
$$

Edit: For the general question, it is required that both original and aproximation function have exactly the same equilibria, i.e. that the approximation doesn't add any new equilibira.

Comment: There's a glitch in your definition of sgn. Also, a proof by exhaustion seems easier than looking at tanh function.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo. But even if it is easier to proof otherwise, I would still like to know whether this works...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the second question is *generally* NO.  Consider a family $f_a(x) = x (x - \frac{1}{a}) (x + \frac{1}{a})$, $a > 0$.  One has $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} f_a(x) = x^3$, uniformly for $x$ in compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  The equilibrium $0$ is (even asymptotically) stable for any $\dot{x} = f_a(x)$, whereas it is unstable for the limiting equation $\dot{x} = x^3$.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting example. However I should add to the question that the approximation function $f_a$ is not supposed to have different equilibria than the original $f$.

Comment: If for $f$ there is a nbhd of $0$ such that there are no equilibria except $0$, then stability means that $f$ is negative to the right of $0$ and positive to the left of $0$ (in that nbhd), so (if we restrict ourselves to continuous functions) approximating functions with the same equilibria should have that property.  And if $0$ is an accumulation point of equilibria then it is stable (at least from one side), so $0$ is stable for approximating functions, too.

Comment: Thats what I suspect too... is there any theorem available that gives a rigorous proof for this? Especially for the multidimensional case that would be interesting...

Comment: No, I don't know of any theorem.  Now I think that uniqueness of solutions is needed for that result:  if there is a sequence of equlibria converging to $0$ then each solution is sandwiched between two equlibria, which gives stability (and without uniqueness; who knows?).    In the multidimensional case, I have no ideas.

Comment: But if you have a system that is globally asymptotically stable for all $a$ then the limit case would be stable as well. But in your example the basin of attraction of the origin is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|-\frac{1}{a}<x<\frac{1}{a}\}$, so not globally. And by taking the limit of this set it is indeed obvious that its size would become zero.

Comment: @Kwin van der Veen:  Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Do you know a theorem for this? Or how do you know that the limit case will be stable as well?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the method with the limit is always possible, but I am also looking forward to an answer that explains if it is applicable at all or if it is applicable under certain conditions.

This is the reason why this is not an answer for the applicability of the limit for the stability analysis of this system. I will rather show a direct method to investigate the stability of the nonlinear system.

First, note that $x=0$ is an equilibrium point of the nonlinear system. Then integrate the equation exploiting that $\text{sgn}(x)$ can be treated as a constant.

$x(t)=-\text{sgn}(x)t+c$

Edit: In order to motivate this solution you can look at three cases $x>0$, $x=0$ and $x<0$. For the first case, we obtain $$\dot{x}=-1 \implies x(t) = -t+ c_1.$$ The case $x=0$ leads to $$\dot{x}=0 \implies x(t) = c_2.$$

The last case results in

$$\dot{x} = +1 \implies x(t) = t + c_3$$

Combining all cases gives the previous expression.

If $x(t=0)=x_0$ then we can look at the two cases $x_0>0$ and $x_0<0$. Can you continue?

Comment: More like $x(t)=-\text{sgn}(x)x+c=-|x|+c$, is't it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typo

Comment: I dont really get why $x(t) = -\text{sgn}(x)x + c$?

Comment: The question asks whether stability of (2) $\dot x=f(a,x)$ for every $a$ implies stability of (1) $\dot x=g(x)$ on general grounds, under the condition that $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}f(a,x)=g(x)$. Where do you address this?

Comment: @Did: Thank you for you comment. The answer was not meant to be answering this aspect of the question.

Comment: @SampleTime: Sorry for the confusion. It should have been $x(t)=-\text{sgn}(x)t+c$.

Comment: But THIS IS the question, no?

Comment: @Did: I think this is the first part of the question, which consists of two questions. See: What is an easy method to check for stability. The second part is about the limit.

Comment: Sorry but you do not either answer the question "If it is shown that $(2)$ is stable for all $a > 0$, does that also show stability of $(1)$ because $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow \infty} \tanh(a x) = \text{sgn}(x) \,?$", it seems, since this asks to **deduce** the stability of $(1)$ **from** the stability of $(2)$ and the pointwise limit of $\tanh(ax)$.

Comment: @MrYouMath Ok now I get it, so the system is of course stable, thanks. The second question is basically what Did said... would be really interesting to know if this works in general, or only under certain conditions (and if so, which conditions)...

Comment: @SampleTime: Yes, I am also looking forward to an answer to this part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a first order system of the form

$$
\dot{x} = f(x)
$$

then any function, that goes through the origin and satisfies the constraint $x\,f(x) < 0\ \forall\ x\neq0$, would make the system [asymptotically stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Globally_asymptotically_stable_equilibrium).

To show this one can use the following Lyapunov function

$$
V(x) = x^2
$$

such that

$$
\dot{V}(x) = 2\,x\,f(x)
$$

so applying the constraint yields $\dot{V}(x)<0\ \forall\ x\neq0$.